# Sencha xtype navigation fails when adding initialize function

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a Home.js view with some embedded xtype's for subpages in a bottom bar. First I added the other Views in the config and all was fine, but now I need to set some other stuff (i.e. username) using the initalize method.

But, now the navigation to the other views doesn't fire anymore. Nothing happens, no action is fired or any error. The view is still shown correctly.

**The View**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Home', {
extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
id : 'home',
xtype : 'homeview',
requires : ['Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.Video', 'MyApp.view.Profile'],

initialize : function() {

    console.log('Initializing Home');
    var me = this
    var config = me.getInitialConfig();
    var username = config.username;
    var items = [];

    items.push({
        xtype : 'titlebar',
        docked : 'top',
        title : 'Hello ' + username
    }, {
        xtype : 'updatesview',
    }, {
        xtype : 'searchview',
    }, {
        xtype : 'profileview'
    }, {
        xtype : 'messagesview'
    }, {
        xtype : 'sensesview'
    });

    me.setItems(items);

    console.log('Initializing Home');
},
config : {
    title : 'Home',
    iconCls : 'home',
    tabBarPosition : 'bottom'

}

});
```

Switching back to this works (????)

**The old view, using only config**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Home', {
extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
id : 'home',
xtype : 'homeview',
requires : ['Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.Video', 'MyApp.view.Profile'],

config : {
    title : 'Home',
    iconCls : 'home',
    tabBarPosition : 'bottom',
    items : [{
        xtype : 'updatesview',
    }, {
        xtype : 'searchview',
    }, {
        xtype : 'profileview'
    }, {
        xtype : 'messagesview'
    }, {
        xtype : 'sensesview'
    }]
}

});
```

**Update**

I tried both

```
me.setItems(items);
me.addItems(items);
```

None work.

**Update 2**

OK the problem lies with the initialize function. ANY init disables the navigation (??)

```
initialize : function() {
    console.log('init home');
},
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to call the parent init method in your init:

```
...
initialize : function() {
  this.callParent(arguments);
  ...
  // Rest of your code...
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside initialize function try creating the objects first and then add them to container like this

```
var items = [];
items.push(Ext.create("SecretSensation.view.Updatesview"));
items.push(Ext.create("SecretSensation.view.searchview"));
items.push(Ext.create("SecretSensation.view.profileview"));
items.push(Ext.create("SecretSensation.view.messagesview"));
items.push(Ext.create("SecretSensation.view.sensesview"));
me.add(items);
```

Comment: this makes no difference, the links and buttons appear in the bottom bar, but they are just 'dead'...